# Difference in Periodic Tables in Block Formation (split in d-block)

Tags: orbitals, periodic-table

I had a question. When I was learning Chemistry and blocks in the periodic table, my professors always broke the table down like the image below

[image]

Recently, when I looked up the periodic table (in block form), I noticed that the first group of the d-block was separated off from the rest of the d-block. So, rather than it going very neatly s, f, d, p (as it does in the picture above), it now goes s, one group of d, f, the other 9 groups of d, then p (like the image below).

[image]

Can someone please explain this to me? I am not a chemistry major or even good at chemistry, just curious. I thought it may have something to do with electron configurations (1s2 2s2 2p6... etc) but when I tried it out, I couldn't understand. If you could explain it in layman terms, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Just different formatting. You can see from your own examples that the lower table is almost readable, the upper table isn't even close.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that aspect (as in why block F is placed below the periodic table in order to fit on an 8.5x11).

Comment: What I do not understand is why, in the extended form, does the F-block sometimes come after the s-block but in more modern periodic tables it falls inbetween the d-block (as I mentioned in the description, it goes s-block, one group in the d-block, THEN the f-block, followed by the rest of the d-block....)